# Some builds crash deployed with testflight

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, testflight

We've developed an AR app using Unity 2018.1.8f1 and AR Kit, we deploy on testflight to two iPads to test it.
One [0] iPad 2017 running iOS 12 beta 4, the other [1] iPad 2017 Pro iOS 11.
Both of them could run the testflight build that was deployed until after build number 50 where the iPad [1] would have problems, launching it you would see the unity splashscreen but immediately afterwards it crashes. This crash happens at the same time that AR Kit initializes, on non ar supported devices it crashes here as well.
Future builds would also fail on iPad[1]

Both iPads can downgrade to an older build and can run those versions fine. It can also take the same build and be installed via XCode and have it work there without crashing.

Does anyone know what could cause this issue and how to resolve it if it's related to the iPad used or something in the build process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occured when the model used was replaced with a new one (identical but with new textures)
The solution was to in Xcode under Build settings disable Compress PNG files & Remove Text metadata from PNG files.